# Is there a way to have position absolute in a position static container?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of tiles that flow nicely using inline-block, but the tiles need to have position absolute to put various other elements in their necessary positions.

Is there any way I can position absolute in my inline-block element?

From what I've read position absolute will apply to the next parent that isn't position static, so I know it's either impossible, or I need a work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the tiles as `display: inline-block`

Set `position:relative` on each tile

Set `position:absolute` on the elements within the tile that need absolute positioning

Comment: I'm trying this now. It looks like the inline-block breaks.
Your solution is very clever and most importantly is technically correct, but things aren't quite working out as I expect them in js fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/BQHcr/

Comment: I decided to try the fix on my real problem and it fixed it. Your awesome man! You also replied in less than 5 minutes. I'm so happy.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell Just for the info, IE versions prior to IE8 don't support inline-block: http://caniuse.com/inline-block